# javascript array contains values called empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Not sure what is going on but when I update my store state by deleting items, it's saying that the items are empty.

see screenshot

[image]

and therefore the array is still of the same length?

these are my functions:

```
export const deleteUserFromFirebase = ({ id, name, username, email }) => {
  return firebase
    .database()
    .ref("/users/" + id)
    .set({
      id: null
    });
};


export const deleteUserFromStoreThenUpdateFirebase = user => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return dispatch(deleteUser(user)).then(() => {
      return deleteUserFromFirebase(user);
    });
  };
};


export const deleteUser = user => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: DELETE_USER, user: user });
  };
};
```

and I call `deleteUserFromStoreThenUpdateFirebase` from a button click

why would it be doing this??

also my reducer does this:

```
case DELETE_USER: {
  return {
    ...state,
    users: state.users.filter(u => u.id !== action.user.id)
  };
}
```

well confused right now

also firebase is showing the correct amount of nodes and when i refresh it's suppose to be pulling from firebase but it pulls the empty ones too

Comment: What does your initial `users` state look like?

Comment: it's an object with an array of users inside

Comment: Could you include that code in the question?